# Can I limit the amount of command usages in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, discord.js

I am currently making a Discord bot for my friends, and I want to limit the amount of times they can use a particular command every hour. I am using the jsoning npm package for a database, but I am having troubles resetting it. I have it storing the usage amount in a database by their ID, and this is where I run into a problem trying to reset all the usage amounts at the same time. This is the code I have for a work command, and it shows how I am storing the usage amounts. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

````
if (command === 'work') { 
    if(await database.has(`uses${message.author.id}`) == false) await database.set(`uses${message.author.id}`, 3)
    var starting = await database.get(`uses${message.author.id}`)
    if(starting < 1) return message.channel.send('**Please wait until next hour to use again!**')
    await database.math(`uses${message.author.id}`, 'subtract', 1)
    var output = await eco.Work(message.author.id, {
      failurerate: 20,
      money: Math.floor(Math.random() * 500),
      jobs: [mechanic, subway worker]
    })
    //10% chance to fail and earn nothing. You earn between 1-500 coins. And you get one of those 3 random jobs.
    if (output.earned == 0) return message.reply('**You did your job so well so you earned nothing!**')
 
    message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}
You worked as a \` ${output.job} \` and earned  w$${output.earned}
You now own w$${output.balance}**`)
  }```
````

Comment: Do you want them to just be able to use it once an hour? (Or, the simpler way to do it, is once per time period i.e. if you want 4 times an hour, that is the same as once every 15 mins)

Comment: I want them to use it 3 times per hour, but I am having trouble resetting the number of uses back to 3 when the hour changes.

Comment: If you made it so they can use it once every 20 mins, you could just use a set instead